# UIRefreshControl - Refresh not work on UITableView with custom cell

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell, uirefreshcontrol

I have a tableView worked without error, and I can renew and add new cell to the tableview after I add new row from my database by pressing a button from other view. But this "pull to refresh" method didn't refresh and add new cell.

on my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init] ;

  [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTableview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged] ;
  [self.myTableView addSubview:refreshControl] ;
}
```

on my refreshTableview method: (loadData is a method to get data from my DB)

```
-(void) refreshTableview {
  [self loadData]
  [self.myTableView reloadData] ;
  [refreshControl endRefreshing] ;
}
```

Below is my button method that work good to refresh the view (loadData is a method to get data from my DB)

```
    [self loadData] ;
    [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[imageArray, uploadTimeArray, uploaderNameArray, uploadEmailArray, uploadProfilePicArray] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone] ;
```

I tried to parse this line on refreshTableview method,

```
    [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[imageArray, uploadTimeArray, uploaderNameArray, uploadEmailArray, uploadProfilePicArray] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone] ;
```

But "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error appear. Can anyone suggest a way to let me refresh the tableview correctly with this "pull to refresh" method?